# c++ can't return a inherited class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having a trouble with polymorphism, here is the thing. I'm working with rapidjson, after I have the JSON String and convert it, I need a method to send an object of SUPERCLASS InternalMsg, but I need to send inherited class objects.

Example

```
class InternalMsg{
public:
    virtual ~InternalMsg() {};
};

class Event: InternalMsg{

public:

    Event(){};

    char* type;
    char* info;
};


class ScanResult : public InternalMsg{
public:
  int id_region;
  int result;
};
```

This are the classes, this is the method, like I say, I'm working with rapidjson:

```
InternalMsg* JsonPackage::toObject(){

    Document doc;
    doc.Parse<0>(this->jsonString);

    if(doc["class"] == "Event"){
        Event* result = new Event;
        result->type= (char*)doc["type"].GetString();
        result->info = (char*)doc["info"].GetString();
        return result;
    }else{
        std::cout << "No object found" << "\n";
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The method is incomplete and in the line of return have a fail.

I try making a cast but when I use typeid().name() I have InternalMsg but not the inherited class name.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the exact error message.

Comment: InternalMsg* result = new Event;

Comment: @willll: That won't work either. Even if it did, you wouldn't be able to use `result` to access `type` and `info`.

Comment: The error message is:   conversion is not allowed in the inaccessible base class

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Right ! Event constructor should set them IMO...

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. If you have to use `reinterpret_cast` to make your code work, you've probably done something wrong.

Comment: You are right Neil... I will try with that function... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using private inheritance, because the default for `class` is `private`:

```
class Event: InternalMsg {
```

This means `Event` *is-not-an* `InternalMsg`, and the conversion from `Event*` to `InternalMsg*` cannot take place.

You should use public inheritance:

```
class Event: public InternalMsg {
```

or, since all your members are public anyway, use the fact that the default for `struct` is `public`:

```
struct Event: InternalMsg {
```

Comment: Correct... That was the problem... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please note that it's generally considered bad style to have public data in your class/struct. The explicit public inheritance should therefore be preferred over the implicit version using a struct.

Comment: @JorenHeit Whatever. I don't subscribe to that view.

Comment: @juanchopanza You don't subscribe to data hiding in general? Heresy!

Comment: @JorenHeit I subscribe to using things when they are needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza So do I, but given a forum at which answers are used by both novices and experienced programmers, in all kinds of different contexts, I think it's best to give precedence to best practices. Programmers experienced enough to deviate from such dogma will make that choice when they see fit.